# afxwin.h(112): fatal error C1189: #error : MFC requires use of Winsock2.h

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am trying to build libfreenect lib files.After,successfully making the solution file using Cmake (Following all the procedure as described in Openkinect); while I am trying to build the solution,I am getting the following error.

***afxwin.h(112): fatal error C1189: #error :  MFC requires use of Winsock2.h***

Can anyone give me some ideas about resolving this?
I am using visual studio 2010.

Comment: This is probably because you have #included winsock.h at some point before you #included the MFC headers (which must use Winsock2.h). You need to make sure that the MFC headers are included first.

Comment: Thanks Rowland!
It works;but,unfortunately new errors occurred.     

**'usb_libusb10.h(72): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cb'**      

Eventhough,its clear there are no syntax errors.I have found some where else it might caused due to missing windows.h header.So,just to let you know I have declared that and still facing the error.Will be very glad if u (or,anyone else) can help!!